# Docusign Rest API: Not able to associate docusign with salesforce record

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I am in salesforce and when say Opportunity record is created, I am using DocuSign rest api to send the document for signature which includes information from salesforce record. I am creating envelope in apex code and sending to customer using email. I intend to associate the envelope(Docusign status related list) to that particular salesforce record.

I am able to send the envelope in email successfully from apex code but not able to relate it to the source salesforce record.

Below is my json which I am using.

```
{
"templateId":"48fe922d-f395-47d8-97d4-d0047c3c8d18",
"status":"sent",
"emailSubject":"Send Envelope via REST from Salesforce",
"customFields":
    {
        "textCustomFields": 
        [{"value":"0062v000019uceT","show":"false","name":"Opportunity"}]
     }
}
```

FYI, I am bit confused with value(Opportunity) for name property in above json if it is correct. I tried giving different value(DSFSSourceObjectId || field from docusign status object which is lookup to parent opportunity object) as well it did not work.

**Additional Info**

I have installed docusign for salesforce managed package. With this one additional observation, there are two types of account with docusign.

1. 30 day free trial account with which docusign Connect works
   automatically and APIs communication do not. This is the account
   which is created when we install and connect docusign to salesforce
   and reverse under admin tab.
2. Developer Account with which Docusign Connect do not work but api communications can happen.

If my above statements are correct is it true to say that Docusign connect and Docusign API will not work together? If yes, the envelope  created and sent using  docusignAPI in apex will not automatically update the docusign status back in salesforce as it happens with docusign connect for salesforce?  Do we need to poll another api at regular intervals to check the docusign status and  update in salesfoce? Or can it be done in standard way by using docusign connect and API together? Is it something i am not able to do because of free trial version and will be able to do in live org?

Please clarify.

Comment: Your json looks fine--you are adding metadata to the DocuSign envelope.  From where are you having trouble looking up the envelope? What have you tried? Please EDIT your question to show how you are trying to look up the envelope. Also, what does OOTB mean?

Comment: @LarryK  Thank you. I have made the edit to question. Please let me know if not clear

Comment: I just uninstalled and reinstalled the package and established the docusign connect with developer sandbox. With this achieved one milestone where Docusign Status records are now being pushed to salesforce after creating and sending envelope using API. Still the open issue is DocusigStatus record is not getting associated to parent opportunity record. Any help related to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by providing different value for name property in request json.
**"Name":"##SFOpportunity"**